# Unlock on password reset and auto locking no active users in WSO2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Does wso2 has **unlock on password recovery** and **auto locking no active user** features? For example:

1. user will be unlocked if he changes password (if he was locked)
2. if user last authentication was 1 month before, account will be locked

Comment: can you update the question with your usecase ad what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @PiraveenaParalogarajah added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the user is locked, IS doesn't allow to recover the password by user via email or security questions. [Here](https://github.com/wso2-support/identity-governance/blob/54fc7ec090cf86f07e3fd8990f1fffffc785428b/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.recovery/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/recovery/password/NotificationPasswordRecoveryManager.java#L187) you can see the validation prior to password recovery flow.
   However, [admin forced password reset](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/forced-password-reset/) can be used for your case. When the admin forced to reset the password, the user will receive the notification. Upon password resetting, the account will be unlocked.
2. Refer https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/user-account-suspension/

Comment: Does AccountLockHandler handle unlocking through Admin forced password reset? Or i should handle it in password reset component?